# Run time for insertion sort with different size, how do I calculate?

Tags: algorithm, runtime

If I have n random int, it takes x time to run it
Now, I have 6n random int, how long does it take? I use insertion sort.

Last question, if i choose different sort (same size n), how do I calculate it?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to know *exactly*, but there are rules of thumb that will allow you to obtain a very rough approximation of the running time.

Insertion sort is an O(n<sup>2</sup>) algorithm. What that means in the real world is that, all other things being equal, increasing the size of n by some number, x, will increase the running time by approximately n<sup>2</sup>. So if you double the size of n, running time will increase by approximately 4 times. If you multiply n by 6, running time will increase by approximately 36 times.

Unfortunately, you can't always keep other things equal. You have to think about the effects of cache misses, virtual memory, other things running on the computer, etc. Asymptotic analysis isn't really a tool for computing real-world running times, but it can serve as a very rough approximation: a "ball park estimate," if you will.

Other sorting algorithms have different orders of complexity. Merge sort, for example, has computational complexity of O(n log n), meaning that running time increases with the logarithm of the number of items. That increases much more slowly than does n^2. For example, sorting 1,024 items (2^10) requires on the order of (2^10 * 10) comparisons. Sorting 2^20 items will require on the order of (2^20 * 20) comparisons.

I can't stress strongly enough that those calculations are very rough approximations. They'll get you in the area--probably within an order of magnitude--but you'll never get an exact number that way.

What you *can't* do with any degree of certainty is say that if insertion sort takes x time, then merge sort will take y time. Asymptotic analysis ignores constant factors. So you can't even approximate the running time of merge sort based on the running time of insertion sort. Nor, for that matter, can you approximate bubble sort (another O(n^2) algorithm) based on the running time of insertion sort.

The whole idea of using asymptotic analysis to estimate the real world running time of an algorithm is fraught with error. It often works when estimating the running time of one implementation of one algorithm on specific hardware, but beyond that it's useless.

### Update

You asked:

*for n = 2^20, M seconds for merge sort, and B seconds for bubble sort, If I have a different size that takes 4B for bubble sort, how do i know the run time of merge sort?*

As I pointed out above, you cannot estimate the time for merge sort based on the time for bubble sort. What you *can* do, is estimate the running time of merge sort for the new size based on the running time for merge sort at size n=2^20.

For example, at n=2^20, merge sort requires on the order of (2^20 * 20) comparisons. At n=2^21, it requires on the order of (2^21 * 21) comparisons. At n=2^32, (2^32 * 32) comparisons.

What you can do then, is take the expected number of comparisons for your new n, compute the expected number of comparisons, and divide that by (2^20 * 20). So, for example, when n=2^22, the expected number of comparisons is approximately 92,274,688. Divide that by 20,971,520 (2^20 * 20), and you get 4.4. So, if sorting 2^20 items with merge sort takes time x, then sorting 2^22 items will take *approximately* 4.4*x.

Again, let me point out that these are *very rough approximations* that assume everything else remains equal.

Comment: one more short question, for n = 2^20, M seconds for merge sort, and B seconds for bubble sort, If I have a different size that takes 4B for bubble sort, how do i know the run time of merge sort ?

Comment: Than you sir, make sense now